# How to use Entity Framework instead of Ado.net. dataset?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am developing windows application with ado.net but now it seem to be run slow, it takes time to fetch and display data. What should I do? Can I use Entity Framework with stored procedures? And what will be steps?

Comment: Yes - you can use EF, and yes, even with stored procedures - but don't expect any magic speedup from that combo. If your database performance is bad, then it's just as bad with EF and stored procedures.... you need to find (and **fix**!) the root cause of your performance issues....

Comment: Thank you for the guidance..

Answer (score 2):

If you have performance problem switching to EF will not help you. EF is an abstraction layer on top of ADO.NET. You should look at why do you have performance issue with ADO.NET first. Use SQL Server Profiler to identify your issues. [Here is a link on how to start SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx)